# Django: efficient template/string separation and override

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a generic Django view that renders a template. The template is in an app which other projects will use. Importing projects will typically subclass the View the app provides. The View has a default template, which does a job with generic wording.

99% of the time, subclassing Views will want to only change the text, so rather than make them duplicate the template for the sake of altering non-markup wording, i'm looking for a way to allow users of the class to replace wording in the template in the most efficient way.

Options explored so far:

- template partials containing only the text which using apps can override (magic, a lot of user work)
- A `template_strings` method on the view which provides a dict of strings which end up in the template context which subclasses can override
- Using (abusing?) the translation system such that the app provides default english translations and using code can provide their own translations instead (not actually worked this one out yet, just an idea)
- Doing the above `template_strings` through AppConfig, but this seems ... yucky like it may get very unweildy with a lot of English strings. If doing this I would create a context-like setup so you don't have to re-declare all strings

Seems like it should be a solved problem to subclass a view which does a complete job and just provide alternate strings for text. Is there a better method than the above? Convention? Something I am missing?

(django 1.11 Python 3.6.2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either inherit [`TemplateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateView)  or add [`ContextMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/) to your view, and then override the `get_context_data` function like this:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class BaseView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "common.html"

class SubView(BaseView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SubView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['content'] = "Some sub view text"
        return context
```

#### Update: Use template overriding

If you want to separate the text out, this is the better way to go
To allow easily and DRY override template across apps, you might need to install this [package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-apptemplates/) (Some other detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7475745/1149484))

We define it similarly as above, but change the `template_name` instead:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

    class BaseView(TemplateView):
        template_name = "main.html"

    # on another app
    class SubView(BaseView):
        template_name = "sub_view.html"
```

Then the magic is you can `extends` and override `block` of the `BaseView` template like this:

**base_app/templates/main.html**

```
<p>I'm Common Text</p>
{% block main %}
  <p>I'm Base View</p>
{% endblock %}
```

**sub_app/templates/sub_view.html**

```
{% extends "base_app:main.html" %}
{% block main %}
  <p>I'm Sub View</p>
{% endblock %}
```

The result would be:

```
<p>I'm Common Text</p>
<p>I'm Sub View</p>
```

Comment: This is the implementation of bullet-point 2 and is near enough what I have implemented. Having a LOT of strings in get_context_data is grim and farming it out to somewhere _through_ get_context seems to miss the point. I'm thinking the translation module might be the way to go, ie multiple English translations one overriding the other

Comment: @AidenBell: please don't use the English translations, i think it's ugly. Updated my answer with new way by overriding templates.

Comment: Ive selected this one as the answer, but tbh, all the solutions are less than ideal and less than satisfying. This appears to be Django's fault, not the answerers and this I think represents the most idomatic solution but isn't the way I'll be going

Comment: okay, i see, do update if you've found a better solution for your question, for others' reference

Comment: I certainly shall

Answer (score 0):

Afaik you covered the options pretty well. My example is probably just a variant of the the template strings but maybe it helps anyway...

```
class DefaultStringProvider():
    TITLE = 'Hello'
    DESCRIPTION = 'Original description'
    CATEGORY = 'Stuff'

class MyTemplateBaseView(TemplateView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        return super(MyTemplateBaseView, self).get_context_data(
            provider=self.get_string_provider(), **kwargs)

    def get_string_provider(self):
        return DefaultStringProvider()

class OtherView(MyTemplateBaseView):
    template_name = 'welcome.html'

    def get_string_provider(self):
        p = DefaultStringProvider()
        p.TITLE = 'Hello'
        p.DESCRIPTION = 'New description'
        return p
```

The idea is to have a default string provider and the base view populates the context with it through get_string_provider().

It will at least be quite clear which strings can be overridden for a user extending the base class and it will not interfere with translations.